# Calculating Idle time for Uber service

Tags: r

I have uber dataset containing variables pickup point, request time, drop time, date variable without month and year.

I need code for calculating idle time and creating a new variable idle time. Calculation as follows:

If pickup points are same for consecutive rows and date is different for consecutive rows then NA value if not difference between drop time of first row and the pickup time in second row. I have done it in excel and need to do it in R

Attached is the screenshot of data in excel

[image]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and the R code you have tried so far.

Comment: Please have a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that it is easy for others to help you.

Comment: I am very new to programming hence I have no idea how to write it in R

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this, if this is what you are looking for

```
for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
  df$idle[1]<-NA
  if(df$Pickup.point[i]!=df$Pickup.point[i-1])
    df$idle[i]<-NA
  else
    if(df$Date[i]!=df$Date[i-1])
      df$idle[i]<-NA
    else
      df$idle[i]<-(df$Req[i]-df$Drop[i-1])
}
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. grateful for the help:)